# find truth tables and K-Map

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

there are four inputs for the funtion f. the output is 1 if and only if two or three of the four inputs are "1". a. create a truth table for the function f    b. minimize it using K-Maps    c. implement the minimized function using AND and OR gates.

It was a review question and i missed the session....
Anyone please?

Comment: Did you miss one session, or the entire topic? Suggest you google on truth tables, Karnough maps, and/or gates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Product-of-sums (AND of ORs):**

```
(a+b+c) & (a+b+d) & (a+c+d) & (b+c+d) & (!a+!b+!c+!d)
```

**Sum-of-products (OR of ANDs):**

```
!abc + ab!c + !bcd + a!cd + b!cd + ac!d
```

**Karnaugh map:**

```
             ab
       00  01  11  10
      +---+---+---+---+
   00 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   01 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
cd    +---+---+---+---+
   11 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
   10 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+
```